# Linking gcc with g++ code

Tags: gcc, g++

I am trying to link the already existing library in my program. My program is written in C++ and library was developed in C. Now, I am facing the problem while compiling and linking.

I followed many posts of this forum related to linking gcc libraries with g++ sources. Somehow, I could solve some problems. Now, I am facing one problem. Here is detail of my problem.

In testlib.h file

```
int sum(int x, int y)

In testlib.c file

int sum(int x, int y) { 
    return x + y;
}
```

I created the static library of these files.

My next step is to use this function in g++ source code.

In call.hh file,

```
#include<iostream>


#include "testlib.h"

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
    int sum(int x, int y);
}

namespace math_operation {
    void show_addition(int x, int y); 
}
```

I defined this function in call.cc file

```
#include "call.hh"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void math_operation::show_addition(int x, int y){
    cout<<" sum "<<sum(x, y)<<endl;
}
```

Now, I call this function in main.cc

```
#include "call.hh"

using namespace math_operation;
int main() {
    int x = 10;
    int y = 15;
    show_addition(x, y);
    return 0; 
}
```

I have two problems: 
Firstly, it gives compilation error since I have declared the function int sum(int, int) twice. But if I don't declare extern "C" { int sum(int, int) } in call.hh, the compilation problem is solved and linker problem is created with following error:
undefined reference to `sum(int, int)'

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

```
extern "C" {
#include "testlib.h"
}
```

and don't declare it yourself. Should work.

Comment: `gcc -c testlib.c -o testlib.o; g++ main.cc call.cc testlib.o -o main` works.

Answer (score 0):

For `testlib.h` to be usable in C++ files it should have declared the functions as `extern "C"`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int sum(int x, int y);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then when you define `sum` as `extern "C"` the definition matches the declaration, and you don't get either a redeclaration error or undefined reference.

If you can't edit `testlib.h` then you can include it inside an `extern "C"` block, as aragaer's answer shows:

```
extern "C" {
#include "testlib.h"
}
```

(but this is generally a hacky workaround and it's better to fix the library)

You should not declare `sum` in your own `call.hh` file, there's a header that declares it, you should use the header (adding `extern "C"` inside the header or around its `#include` if necessary)